# MongoDB - Using email id as identifier across collections

Tags: mongodb

I have user collection which holds **email_id** and **_id** as unique. I want to store user data across various collections. I would like to use email_id as identifier in those collections. Because it is easy to query in the shell against those collections with email_id instead of complex ObjectId.

Is this right way? will it give any performance problem while creating indexes with big emailIds?

> Also, don't consider this option, If you have plan to enable email_id change
>   option in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While relational databases encourage you to normalize your data and spread it over many tables, this approach is usually not the best for MongoDB. MongoDB doesn't support JOINs over multiple collections or even multiple documents from the same collection. So you should try to design your database documents in a way that each query can be statisfied by searching for a single document. That means it is usually a good idea to store all information about a user in one document.

An exception for this is when certain points of data of the user grows indefinitely (like the posts made by a user in a forum). First, MongoDB documents have a size limit and second, when the size of a document increases, the database needs to reallocate its hard drive space frequently. This slows down writes and leads to fragmentation in the database. In that case it's better to put each entity in a different collection.

The size of the fields covered by an index don't matter when you search for equality. When you have an unique index on email_id, it should be just as fast as searching by _id.